# OnMouseMove dragging, target wrongly intercepting events

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have target that should move around in it's parent, where that parent is clicked.

Some Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GMerZ/

Some HTML:

```
<div id="rControl">
  <p>R1 / R2</p>
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some jQuery via CoffeeScript:

```
rControl = $('#rControl')
widget = rControl.find '.widget'
target = rControl.find '.target'

clicked = no
widget
  .mousedown =>
    clicked = yes

  .mouseup =>
    clicked = no

  .mousemove (e) =>
    if clicked
      target.css
        top:  "#{e.offsetY}px"
        left: "#{e.offsetX}px"
```

Problem is the target jitters around as you drag.  It seems to be that the first event places the widget under the cursor, and the second event occurs *on the target* and not the widget background, so the offset is now relative to the target, not the parent widget, and the offset values are much smaller.  The target now incorrectly moves to the top left of the widget.

Clearly, the target should *not* be handling these events, and should not be providing click location info based on the target's position.

How can I make this work so that I get the mouse position relative to `.widget` on every firing of the event, regardless of whether or not the mouse is in the `.target`?

Also, I'd love to do this without rearranging the HTML forcing the target under the widget, there must be a tricky bit of event delegation magic I'm missing.

Comment: What happens if you use the other X/Y's in the event? Say, `pageX` and `pageY` with adjustments to localize the coordinates to the container.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh those _do_ seem to stay consistent, although in the wrong range.  Not finding yet how to find the page X/Y of the origin of the element I want though.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out `mousemove` calls to only act on the ones fired by `widget`:

Updated JS (just one small change to the `mousemove` `if`):

```
rControl = $('#rControl')
widget = rControl.find '.widget'
target = rControl.find '.target'

clicked = no
widget
  .mousedown =>
    clicked = yes

  .mouseup =>
    clicked = no

  .mousemove (e) =>
    if clicked and e.target == widget[0]
      target.css
        top:  "#{e.offsetY}px"
        left: "#{e.offsetX}px"
```

See [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evictor/GMerZ/1/).

Comment: Problem is that it only fires the code that moves the target once you are _off_ the target.  It's not smooth.  I ended up doing basically this, and using a very small target element so it hits the edge with great granularity.  But I'd like to be able to make the target any size and have it be smooth as butter.

Comment: Here, try this; this is effectively the same and is smooth as butter. :) http://jsfiddle.net/GMerZ/2/ Let me know and I will update answer...

Comment: Well that's not the same either :( If the target was a crosshair gaphic, this would look silly.

Comment: That's no problem, it just needs a little adjustment. Here's a fiddle where the target is centered on the mouse: http://jsfiddle.net/GMerZ/3/